# Send root domain to other website using DNS

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy

Let's say my website lives at **username.site.com** and my domain is me.com

I've seen loads of tutorials which talk about showing my website username.site.com at the web address www.me.com but I don't want to use the www subdomain, I want to show it on my root domain **me.com**

How do I set up my DNS settings so when I visit me.com (no www) it shows the content which is at username.site.com without actually redirecting me there.

Should I be putting a new CNAME record with the value "@" and point to username.site.com?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is a simple thing to do. For your domain name, within your DNS control panel, create a CNAME entry for mysite.com that points to the sub-domain.example.com. That should be it unless you want e-mail to work.

If that is the case, then I suggest using a sub-domain such as mail.mysite.com. If you host your e-mail using a service, then you should follow their instructions, however, again using a CNAME is possible. You would also need a MX record for mysite.com that points to mail.mysite.com. If you get to that point, let us know and we will be glad to help. You can also just leave me a comment here and I will jump and we will get it all working.

Comment: Putting a [CNAME at the DNS root will prevent email from working](https://iwantmyname.com/blog/2014/02/not-receiving-email-check-for-cname-record-on-root-domain.html) for that domain.   You should only use a CNAME for the root when you don't use the domain for email.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That is true. The OP did not mention e-mail so I did not think of that important fact. Ooopppsss!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Updated. Sorta. Cheers!! It has been a while since I have done this, but I can make it work fairly quickly. I do not think the CNAME will really get in the way using the method I have in mind, but if it does, then we can adjust quickly and update the answer.

Comment: `CNAME` is not possible at the apex of a domain, per its design. Various providers offer non standard work arounds often called ANAME or ALIAS.